# Create a local Git repo on Ubuntu box

Tags: git, version-control

I want to create a git repo on my linux box that I can push to or pull from, rather than an externally hosted one like on github. That is to say, I'd need both the local and remote repos to be on the same machine.

Does anyone know how I'd go about doing that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just create a directory somewhere that will act as the 'remote' repository. Run `git init --bare` in that directory. Then, you can clone that repository by doing a git clone --local /path/to/repo. Now you have both a local and 'remote' repository on the same machine and you can push to the remote repository whenever you like.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. :) 
Addendum for anybody who stumbles across this: you need to initialize the intended remote repo with "git init --bare". Otherwise, it works perfectly.